# How to render a flatlist items with dynamic height?

Tags: react-native

I want a UI like this:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnheS.jpg)

I want to show card with dynamic height like in the photo, I tried using columns in flatlist but it takes same height in each row.

This is happening right now:
[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUZqo.png)

This is what I have tried so far

My code-

Product Card:

```
const ProductCard = ({
  title,
  description,
  photoHeight,
  lockStatus,
  imgUrl,
  onPress,
}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.container]}>
      <View
        style={{
          height: photoHeight || 177,
          width: '100%',
        }}>
        <FastImage style={{flex: 1, borderRadius: 20}} source={imgUrl} />
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          padding: 10,
          gap: 10,
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            width: '100%',
          }}>
          <Typography.H color={colors.points}>{title}</Typography.H>
          <LockStatus lockStatus={lockStatus} />
        </View>
        <Typography.H1>{description}</Typography.H1>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

styles of card:

```
import {StyleSheet, Dimensions, Platform} from 'react-native';
import {colors} from '../../config/colors';
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '45%',
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: colors.chipGray,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: colors.white,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 3,
      },
      android: {
        elevation: 4,
      },
    }),
    marginHorizontal: 8,
  },
});
```

Flatlist:

```
        <OptimizedFlatlist
          contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
          renderItem={listItems}
          data={arr}
          numColumns={2}
        />
```

Flatlist styles:

```
  flatListContainer: {
    gap: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
  },
```

listItems:

```
  const listItems = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <ProductCard
        title={'KFC'}
        photoHeight={item}
        description={'Buy 1 Get 1 Everything at ₹199'}
      />
    );
  };
```

sample array
const arr = [150, 29, 200, 49, 54, 66, 71, 80, 90, 10];

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a multiple column FlatList where the rendered items' height do not match the one next to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74048293/make-a-multiple-column-flatlist-where-the-rendered-items-height-do-not-match-th)

Comment: Ah yes it does, Thanks alot!